# How do I determine if pgAgent is installed on a Postgres instance?

Tags: postgresql

I have inherited some problems and I need to determine if pgAgent exists on some number of installations (CentOS) and is running background jobs. These jobs could be run from cron, pgAgent, or an external caller.

If I am looking at a postgres instance and not using pgAdmin, how can I determine if pgAgent is installed?

Can this be done from the command line or from the `psql` client? I'd prefer that to pgAdmin if possible.

Comment: This will probably be different for different operating systems. What are the OS that you are interested in?

Comment: Linux, specifically CentOS with postgres installed to /opt/pgsql .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Database setup](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/pgagent-install.html):

> pgAgent stores its configuration in the ‘postgres’ database in your
>   cluster

And it creates there a schema named `pgagent` with a handful of tables prefixed by `pga_`

It's probably good enough to connect to the `postgres` database and interpret the result of:

```
select 1  from information_schema.schemata  where schema_name='pgagent';
```

Due to how `information_schema.schemata` is restricted, the above should be run as `postgres` user (otherwise consider querying directly `pg_namespace` as the non-standard alternative).